# Authenticate Firebase request with server side API using existing client session

Tags: javascript, authentication, firebase, firebase-security

I'm trying to figure out the best way to authenticate a Firebase request with a **server side API endpoint** using an *existing session* held with the user on the **client app**.

Let's say want an endpoint called `generateKey` that writes a *generated key* to a users Firebase profile object that only an authenticated user can write too:

```
http://example.com/generateKey?id=qwerty123
```

The user has a pre-existing authenticated session with the target Firebase through the client app. The user needs to `generateKey` through this endpoint. I could pass the `auth.token` as a parameter to the API endpoint like:

```
http://example.com/generateKey?id=qwerty123&token=abc123
```

And then use `ref.authWithCustomToken(TOKEN)` in the route handling the API request server side.

This method seems to work but is this the right way to do this?

Comment: Hi Dan. Is this the right what to do what? Without the use case, it's hard to comment on whether this would be effective. It does look functional. Why would the server need to impersonate a user? Could it not simply have its own creds to access the data? I suspect there are some existing constraints we're missing in the discussion.

Comment: @Kato So there's three pieces here (Client App, API server, Firebase Server). I can't see a way my API server can verify the authenticity of a request made from the client app without checking for a users existing session on the client. If someone makes an arbitrary request to my API without an existing Firebase session - how would I verify the authenticity of that request without passing the auth token around?

Comment: A simple answer would be to have the user write the request into Firebase and have the server read it there, rather than adding a RESTful API to the mix. If the user has permissions to write then they are authenticated (assuming you've set up appropriate security rules to enforce this). See [firebase-work-queue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-work-queue)